# Using Xamarin Android without Using Attributes for AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm creating an app in Xamarin Android. It has a custom URI scheme and universal link support, and the specific URI schemes and universal link domains that are used are different depending on whether I'm building the production app or a test version of the app for QA purposes. These settings ultimately end up in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file as intent filters.

[Xamarin's documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Intent_Actions_and_Features) indicates that when developing Xamarin Android apps, custom attributes can/should be used to specify the intent filters on the `Activity` classes. The Xamarin build process then converts these to the relevant XML sections at build time, and injects them into the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

This is helpful, but it is a little restricting when I'm using an automated build process to swap out some of the properties of these intent filters at build time. Ideally, I'd like to control these sections of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file manually myself, so I can have my build script update the relevant sections and add/remove/change the intent filter sections directly.

My question is whether this is possible, and/or supported. Can I simply omit the `IntentFilterAttribute` declarations on my `Activity` class and set them in the XML file safely? Or, does Xamarin require that I use its filter attributes, and would avoiding this be problematic for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, I filed an enhancement this morning regarding advanced manifest merging: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52857

One problem with doing it in the XML file vs. the `[Attribute]` is that some of these items won't be generated until build time (EX: your `<activity>` element). Thus it is much more preferred to do it as an attribute so that when generating that element, it also knows what intent filters to put inside it.

If you have a build process which is finding the correct `<activity>` node and inserting the children below, it can work however it is very "error prone" in the Xamarin.Android build system.

So although the attributes are not required, they are recommended for safety reasons. These attributes prevent you from shooting your own foot with manual `AndroidManifest.xml` modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and that's good timing :) I had suspected that this would be the case. It would certainly be great to be able to use something like config transforms from .NET configuration files to manipulate the AndroidManifest.xml in a future release. In the meantime, I have resorted to twiddling the attributes Activity.cs file at build time just before the compile step - not ideal, and not easy to do, but it works! I'll keep an eye on the enhancement. Thanks.